# Inserting rows in table and keeping track of list order

Tags: database

I have the following table:

```
- id (PK, int, Autoincrement)
- fk (foreign key, int)
- somedata (whatever)
- list_order (int)
```

I need to return somedata in order as defined by list_order for a given fk.  No problem: `SELECT somedata FROM myTable WHERE fk=123 ORDER BY list_order`.

My question relates to how best to add a record should I wish it to be the last record for a given FK.  Will I first need to do a MAX(list_order) for a given fk query, and then a separate query to insert the new row, or can I somehow do this in one query?  Note that the order of the records might be changed, so I cannot simply get rid of list_order, and use ORDER BY id.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it one query:

```
INSERT INTO tableX
  ( fk, somedata, list_order)
SELECT
    fk, @somedata, MAX(list_order) + 1
FROM tableX
WHERE fk = @fk ;
```

The downside that if you have many concurrent insert statements, two (or more of them) may try to insert the same values into the `fk` and `list_order` columns. So, since you probably have a `UNIQUE` constraint in the `(fk, list_order)` combination, all but one of them will fail.

Comment: Thanks, I will most certainly use this approach.  Just curious, is it generally a good idea to use INSERT/SELECT queries instead of doing two separate queries and gluing it together using server code (PHP, etc)?